SQL Server "Refresh Credentials" Option Missing

Usually there's an option for Refresh Credentials, but I don't see it on mine, why is that?
I hope someone can help me.
SQL Server v18, not sure if its version problem.

There is no SQL Server v18 - the SQL Server core/engine is typically referred to with year numbers - 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022. The latest one (2022) is internally v16 - v18 will be out in probably 4, 5 years from now. So what are you really working with? Show us the output of SELECT @@VERSION - that'll tell you (and us) all the details!

v18 usually refers to the management studio version, which is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some; alarming from a supposed mechanic.

If you script the connection to a new window and look at the resulting JSON does the credential object contain a RefreshToken property?
